# How to change text color in a hotkey using MFC?

Tags: mfc, hotkeys, visual-c++-2005

The question is like this: define a new class inheritance `CHotKeyCtrl`, I want to change the text color in hotkey. Using `ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT`,but the test color is not changed.the `onctlcolor` function cannot run.

```
MyHotKey.h
class CMyHotKey: public CHotKeyCtrl
{
   DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CMyHotKey)
   protected:
   DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
   public: 
   afx_msg HBRUSH CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor);
};
MyHotKey.cpp    
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyHotkey, CHotKeyCtrl) 
   ON_WM_CTLCOLOR_REFLECT()
   ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
HBRUSH CMyHotKey::CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor)
{
   if(pDC)
   {
       pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(255,0,0));
       pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
   }
   return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
}
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio do you use? What exactly do you mean by `the onctlcolor function cannot run` -- do you get a compile error, run-time error, ...?

Comment: Visual Studio 2005. No error but the hotkey text color cannot change,the text is drawn with a background system color (COLOR_WINDOW), WM_CTLCOLOR is not called.

Comment: a) Do you have a CTLCOLOR handler in the parent window? [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeah46xd(v=vs.80).aspx) says `...if you handle WM_CTLCOLOR in your dialog box class, your handling will override any reflected message handlers...`
b) try returning a non-null brush, like `return GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW);`

Comment: @Edward Clements a)Edit control text color can be changed in this way in my dialog.b)Return a non-null cannot change the text color. CMyHotkey can not seem to respond to WM_COLOR message. Are there any other ways to change HotKey ctrl text color?

Comment: Maybe there's a misunderstanding -- according to the MSDN article I quoted above, if you have a `WM_CTLCOLOR` handler in the dialog box class, it will override what you do in `CMyHotKey::CtlColor()`; if you place a breakpoint in `CMyHotKey::CtlColor()`, does the execution come there?

Comment: @Edward Clements I place a breakpoint in CMyHotKey::CtlColor(),but it does not execution. It does not find WM_COLOR by spa++.there is no WM_CTLCOLOR handler in the dialog box class. Edit control can change the text color in the same way. What is the difference between CHotKey and CEdit in WM_COLOR?

Comment: a) what is the parent of the `CMyHotKey`? (`CDialog`-derived, or some other class?) b) try returning `FALSE` in `CMyHotKey::OnEraseBkgnd()`

Comment: @Edward Clements a)CMyHotKey parent class is CHotKeyCtrl  b)returning FALSE in CMyHotKey::OnEraseBkgnd() can not change the text color.

Comment: sorry, I meant the window that is hosting the hot key control -- CDialog-derived, or some other class?

Comment: @Edward Clements  the window is CDialog-derived

Comment: I've searched everywhere, even in the MFC sources of `CHotKeyCtrl`, but I cannot find a reason why this does not work -- the last resort is to handle `WM_CTLCOLOR` in your dialog class and check for the ID of your control like in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wwk06hc(v=vs.80).aspx)...

Comment: Thank you.I decided to use editctrl instead of CHotKeyCtrl.